# how to send checkbox value on next page

Tags: php, checkbox

how to send check box value in to next page without submit button and without action.
here i am going to next page using link so i want that these checkbox value send on next.php
my form is

```
 <form method="post" action="" name="Logreg" style="padding-left:35px; padding-bottom:35px; font-size:14px;">
      <input name="pay_type" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $monthly; ?>"id="chk_Box102"  onClick="toggle_2(this);" >
      &nbsp;&nbsp;Monthly<br /><br />
      <input name="pay_type" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $yearly; ?>" id="chk_Box103"  onClick="toggle_2(this);">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;Yearly<br /><br />
      <input name="pay_type" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $lifetime; ?>" id="chk_Box104"  onClick="toggle_2(this);">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;Lifetime
  </form>
```

and here a link by using i am going to next page

```
 <a href="next.php">go here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To post data from one page to another page *you have to use a `submit` button* like:

```
 <form method="post" action="next.php" name="Logreg" style="padding-left:35px; padding-bottom:35px; font-size:14px;">
  <input name="pay_type" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $monthly; ?>"id="chk_Box102"  onClick="toggle_2(this);" >
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Monthly<br /><br />
  <input name="pay_type" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $yearly; ?>" id="chk_Box103"  onClick="toggle_2(this);">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Yearly<br /><br />
  <input name="pay_type" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $lifetime; ?>" id="chk_Box104"  onClick="toggle_2(this);">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Lifetime

    <input type="submit" value="Go here" />

</form>
```

also specify receiving page in `action` attribute of `<form>`

In another page (`next.php`).

You have to access your posted values using `$_POST['name']`;

eg.

```
echo $_POST['pay_type'];
```

**EDIT**

In your code, I can see that you want to send multiple values for checkbox `pay_type`, for that you have to write it as an array (`name="pay_type[]"`)in HTML to send multiple values.

So, the complete code will looks like:

```
 <form method="post" action="next.php" name="Logreg" style="padding-left:35px; padding-bottom:35px; font-size:14px;">
  <input name="pay_type[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $monthly; ?>"id="chk_Box102"  onClick="toggle_2(this);" > Monthly<br /><br />

  <input name="pay_type[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $yearly; ?>" id="chk_Box103"  onClick="toggle_2(this);"> Yearly<br /><br />

  <input name="pay_type[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $lifetime; ?>" id="chk_Box104"  onClick="toggle_2(this);"> Lifetime

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go here" />

</form>
```

Code in `next.php`:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST['pay_type']);  //it will print complete array of values for pay_type checkbox
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Log1c ツ as said before you need a button.. :). What is also possible to use an attribute onClick:

Add an ID at your form tag (`id="myForm"`) (dont forget the target page `next.php` in `action`)

```
<form method="post" action="next.php" name="Logreg" style="padding-left:35px; padding-bottom:35px; font-size:14px;" id="myForm">
```

and then the onClick attribute

```
<a href="next.php" onClick="document.forms['myForm'].submit();">go here</a>
```

[jsfilleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/qfw7tLbe/1/)